# How to show several images under one slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics, itemize, frame-title

I am trying to show several images under one frame. Here, I'm trying to show the coloring of a node in frame. My idea was to itemize the images and disappear the rest except the one I'm talking about. My idea failed because the `\item` s are listed one under another. And they actually reflect my idea. But the images go out of the display area.
Here's my code:

```
\subsection{Coloring the first node}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Coloring the first node}
 \centering
 \begin{itemize}
  \item<1>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{1.jpg}
  \item<2>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{2.jpg}
  \item<3>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{3.jpg}
  \item<4>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{4.jpg}
  \item<5>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{5.jpg}
  \item<6>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{6.jpg}
  \item<7>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{7.jpg}
  \item<8>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{8.jpg}
  \item<9>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{9.jpg}
  \item<10>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{10.jpg}
  \item<11>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{11.jpg}
  \item<12>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{12.jpg}
  \item<13>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{13.jpg}
  \item<14>[] \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{14.jpg}
 \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Why not have a different frame for each image if you just want each image alone at one time?

Comment: Actually, it's not a necessity. I have 100 images in total. It seems a bit awkward to use 100+ frames in a presentation.

Comment: Perhaps a foreach loop (if the images are named like this) plus the only command, look it up in the manual

Comment: Maybe `\multiinclude` from the `xmpmulti` package is of interest for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after? The height of the images should be the same, though.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Coloring the first node}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}}
  \only<2>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
  \only<3>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
  \only<4>{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.8]
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{1} \\ \framebreak
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{2} \\ \framebreak
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{3} \\ \framebreak
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{4} \\ \framebreak
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{5} \\ \framebreak
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{6}
 \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

If all images have the same width, than changing the allowframebreaks to a number that you want, between 0 and 1, it gives me 6 frames with different images 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: It just shows the first image preceded by an empty frame. Then it skips all the following images and goes to my next subsection.

Comment: @Dipto_Das what if you try it without the itemize? Do you really need it to itemize? I've done dus with 5 images in one of my presentations to make it act like a kind of a gif, and it works. But I made I with [width=1\textwidth]

Comment: Sorry @Arne I didn't get that. You suggested to use itemize in your code snippet too. How to do it without itemize?

Comment: it worked with only one problem that the image set are preceded and followed by one empty frame each.

Comment: I'm still trying to adapt the code ;-)

Comment: @Dipto_Das Does the new code work? If the blanc frame still exists, may be reduce allowframebreaks to a smaller number, or after the \\ you could write \framebreak.

Comment: page count still increases. But blank frame problem was solved. But happy to say that egreg's solution did just what I wanted.
Many many thanks for being so helpful.